# TransportError while deleting elasticsearch index by Python script

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have installed `elasticsearch2.1.1` in my `windows` machine and i have an elasticsearch index which is hosted in my machine locally as i am trying to understand it better. Name of the index is `library`. Below is how it looks like.

[image]

I am trying to delete the existing index using python library `elasticsearch` and below is the code to do so.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch('localhost:9200')
if es.indices.exists(index='library'):
    es.delete('library')
```

When i execute this code, i end up getting below error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TransportError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-2a4b3642a164> in <module>()
      1 from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
      2 es = Elasticsearch('localhost:9200')
----> 3 if es.indices.exists(index='library'):
      4     es.delete('library')

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.pyc in _wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     71                 if p in kwargs:
     72                     params[p] = kwargs.pop(p)
---> 73             return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
     74         return _wrapped
     75     return _wrapper

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\indices.pyc in exists(self, index, params)
    222             raise ValueError("Empty value passed for a required argument 'index'.")
    223         return self.transport.perform_request('HEAD', _make_path(index),
--> 224                 params=params)
    225 
    226     @query_params('allow_no_indices', 'expand_wildcards', 'ignore_unavailable',

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\transport.pyc in perform_request(self, method, url, params, body)
    310 
    311             try:
--> 312                 status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
    313 
    314             except TransportError as e:

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.pyc in perform_request(self, method, url, params, body, timeout, ignore)
    126         if not (200 <= response.status < 300) and response.status not in ignore:
    127             self.log_request_fail(method, full_url, url, body, duration, response.status, raw_data)
--> 128             self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
    129 
    130         self.log_request_success(method, full_url, url, body, response.status,

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.pyc in _raise_error(self, status_code, raw_data)
    123             logger.warning('Undecodable raw error response from server: %s', err)
    124 
--> 125         raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
    126 
    127 

TransportError: TransportError(500, u'')
```

Edit: I tried as per suggestion by Slam and used below code

```
a = elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient('localhost:9200')
a.delete(index = 'library')
```

However, i am now getting a new error as follows

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-dc5154b36ad8> in <module>()
----> 1 a.delete(index = 'library')

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.pyc in _wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     71                 if p in kwargs:
     72                     params[p] = kwargs.pop(p)
---> 73             return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
     74         return _wrapped
     75     return _wrapper

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\indices.pyc in delete(self, index, params)
    197         if index in SKIP_IN_PATH:
    198             raise ValueError("Empty value passed for a required argument 'index'.")
--> 199         return self.transport.perform_request('DELETE', _make_path(index),
    200             params=params)
    201 

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.pyc in transport(self)
     82     @property
     83     def transport(self):
---> 84         return self.client.transport
     85 
     86 class AddonClient(NamespacedClient):

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'transport'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Elasticsearch.delete` is made for deleting documents, not indexes.

To operate over idexes, you need [`IndicesClient.delete`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.delete). Indices client is abstraction that works on top of basic ES client, with same transport. Invocation can be

```
>>> es = Elasticsearch('localhost:9200')
>>> es.indices.delete(index='test')
{'acknowledged': True}
```

Comment: Its not working either. I have added the new error and code

Comment: @Enthusiast I've updated answer with example signature. Pls check if it works for you